# Module::Starter not recognizing config file

Tags: perl-module

I have just installed Perl5.24, and Module::Starter.  *module-starter* works fine using all command line arguments, but it does not read a config file found at $HOME/.module-starter/config, even if the environment variable is set and exported as MODULE_STARTER_DIR=$HOME/.module-starter/config.  Wondering if anyone has had this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had that problem. module-starter will look by default for `$HOME/.module-starter/config` and any command line arguments passed to the program will overwrite those read from that file. If you are setting the `MODULE_STARTER_DIR` environment variable, you have to use the path of the directory containing the config file, not the whole path to it.

EDIT:

I think the problem is that module-starter is not finding your configuration file. It looks by default for `$HOME/.module-starter/config` which you have created, but if you have set the `MODULE_STARTER_DIR` environment variable it will look in the directory specified there instead.

The value of the `MODULE_STARTER_DIR` must be the path to the directory in which your configuration file is. For example, if your configuration file is `$HOME/.module-starter/config` then `MODULE_STARTER_DIR` should contain `$HOME/.module-starter/`. But I see you are giving it the whole path to your configuration file.

It's worth noting that since module-starter looks by default for `$HOME/.module-starter/config`, it's redundant setting `MODULE_STARTER_DIR` to `$HOME/.module-starter/`

Comment: After I installed Module::Starter, I created a config file at $HOME/.module-starter/config, and then ran __module-starter --module=Name__, but it would not run because it gave an error that I needed to include an email address.  I had included an email address in the config file.  When I added the environment variable __MODULE_STARTER_DIR__, which pointed to the same config file, __module-starter__ still raised the same error.  When I added my email address to the command line, it ran, but used my computer's name, not the name I gave in the config file.

Comment: Try to set your name and email in your `$HOME/.module-starter/config` and unset `MODULE_STARTER_DIR`